# JavaScript - Convert multiple arrays of an objects to horizonal values based array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple arrays of objects with similar keys, `item` key as being unique identifier in all, I need to display the result in one row for each item with all data of each array of objects.

```
var contracts = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 10,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 100,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 20,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 200,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 30,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 300,
        currency: 'GBP'
    },
    {
        item: 'Four4',
        item_desc: 'This is item number four',
        quantity: 40,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 400,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
];

var orders = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 10,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 100,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 15,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 15,
        currency: 'GBP'
    }
];

var purchase = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 2,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 20,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    }
];

var locations = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 1,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 10,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 7,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 70,
        currency: 'GBP'
    },
    {
        item: 'Five5', // entirely new item, does not exist in in any of above array
        item_desc: 'This is item number five',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'GBP'
    }
];
```

These are the arrays, can be a few more but the data structure remains the same. I would like to have result as below;

```
[
    // [
    //     =============== Example for data below -- this row not required ===============     
    //     "item", "item_desc", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency" ...
    //                           ---------> for contacts <----------    ---------> for orders <-----------     ---------> for purchase <----------    ---------> for locations <---------- ...
    // ],
    [
        "One1", "This is item number one", "10 kg", "100 USD", "5 kg", "50 USD", "2 kg", "20 USD", "1 kg", "10 USD"
    ],
    [
        "Two2", "This is item number two", "20 kg", "200 USD", "10 kg", "100 USD", "5 kg", "50 USD", "5 kg", "50 USD"
    ],
    [
        "Three3", "This is item number three", "30 kg", "300 USD", "15 kg", "150 USD", "-", "-", "7 lb", "70 GBP"
    ],
    [
        "Four3", "This is item number four", "40 kg", "400 USD", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
    ],
    [
        "Five5", "This is item number five", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "5 lb", "50 GBP"
    ],

]
```

I am also trying different manual approaches (loop etc) like I tried doing with looping above each array of objects and pushing to a new array and then again checking for items for the next array and it goes on.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @Andreas I have mentioned in the question: I tried doing with looping above each array of objects and pushing to a new array and then again checking for items for the next array and it goes on. I was looking for some better way

Comment: what is the reason for downvotes? if you want i can add the code what I have described above

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). We're not here to do the research for you. If you have working code and want other opinions on that working code then https://codereview.stackexchange.com might be an option (but check their Help section first)

Comment: Isn't this enough information for clarity of question? I don't think that furthermore research is required. However, if anything is missing you can suggest I will update the question as per criteria. As per the above first comments criteria Search. `Like mad.
Test your code.
Troubleshoot.
Read blogs.
Find books.
Follow tutorials.` these looks do everything first then come here.

Comment: _"any better and efficient way would be highly appreciated"_ is not the topic of SO...

Comment: removed the phrase.

Comment: There's no question. Only a bunch of data. SO is not a free code writing service -> See first comment.

Comment: @Andreas I am not aware if SO has changed the policies recently, but I have seen a lot of similar questions which are answered with only description and answered very well. Even I am not asking to code this for me, a hint would be also beneficial. Thank you for the response, I will try to find out solution somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remap all your data into objects with `item` as a key to avoid iterating through array each time we need to extract something from it:

```js
// Create method for remaping
const remap = arr => arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el.item] = el;
    return acc;
}, {});
// Collect all data in one place
const allData = {
  contracts: remap(contracts),
  orders:    remap(orders),
  purchase:  remap(purchase),
  locations: remap(locations),
};
```

Refs: [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Then we can get all items we have using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to avoid duplicates:

```js
// All possible values of 'item' property
const allItems = [ ...new Set([
  ...Object.keys(allData.contracts), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.orders), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.purchase), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.locations)]) 
];
```

Refs: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

And now we ready to collect data in any format we need via `allData[<arrayName>][<itemProperty>]`, for example (don't forget to check if item exist in specific data object):

```
const result = [];
for (const item of allItems) {
    // =============== Example for data below -- this row not required ===============     
    //     "item", "item_desc", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency" ...
    //                           ---------> for contacts <----------    ---------> for orders <-----------     ---------> for purchase <----------    ---------> for locations <---------- ...
  result.push([
    item,
    allData.contracts[item] 
      ? allData.contracts[item].item_desc
      : '-',
    allData.contracts[item]
      ? allData.contracts[item].quantity + allData.contracts[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.contracts[item] 
      ? allData.contracts[item].value + allData.contracts[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.orders[item]
      ? allData.orders[item].quantity + allData.orders[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.orders[item] 
      ? allData.orders[item].value + allData.orders[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.purchase[item]
      ? allData.purchase[item].quantity + allData.purchase[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.purchase[item] 
      ? allData.purchase[item].value + allData.purchase[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.locations[item] 
      ? allData.locations[item].quantity + allData.locations[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.locations[item] 
      ? allData.locations[item].value + allData.locations[item].currency
      : '-',
  ]);
}
```

Full solution:

```js
const contracts = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 10,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 100,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 20,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 200,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 30,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 300,
        currency: 'GBP'
    },
    {
        item: 'Four4',
        item_desc: 'This is item number four',
        quantity: 40,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 400,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
];

const orders = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 10,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 100,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 15,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 15,
        currency: 'GBP'
    }
];

const purchase = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 2,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 20,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    }
];

const locations = [
    {
        item: 'One1',
        item_desc: 'This is item number one',
        quantity: 1,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 10,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Two2',
        item_desc: 'This is item number two',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'kg',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'USD'
    },
    {
        item: 'Three3',
        item_desc: 'This is item number three',
        quantity: 7,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 70,
        currency: 'GBP'
    },
    {
        item: 'Five5', // entirely new item, does not exist in in any of above array
        item_desc: 'This is item number five',
        quantity: 5,
        unit: 'lb',
        value: 50,
        currency: 'GBP'
    }
];

const remap = arr => arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc[el.item] = el;
    return acc;
}, {});

const allData = {
  contracts: remap(contracts),
  orders:    remap(orders),
  purchase:  remap(purchase),
  locations: remap(locations),
};
const allItems = [ ...new Set([
  ...Object.keys(allData.contracts), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.orders), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.purchase), 
  ...Object.keys(allData.locations)]) 
];

const result = [];
for (const item of allItems) {
    // =============== Example for data below -- this row not required ===============     
    //     "item", "item_desc", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency", "quantity + unit", "value + currency" ...
    //                           ---------> for contacts <----------    ---------> for orders <-----------     ---------> for purchase <----------    ---------> for locations <---------- ...
  result.push([
    item,
    allData.contracts[item] 
      ? allData.contracts[item].item_desc
      : '-',
    allData.contracts[item]
      ? allData.contracts[item].quantity + allData.contracts[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.contracts[item] 
      ? allData.contracts[item].value + allData.contracts[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.orders[item]
      ? allData.orders[item].quantity + allData.orders[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.orders[item] 
      ? allData.orders[item].value + allData.orders[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.purchase[item]
      ? allData.purchase[item].quantity + allData.purchase[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.purchase[item] 
      ? allData.purchase[item].value + allData.purchase[item].currency
      : '-',
    allData.locations[item] 
      ? allData.locations[item].quantity + allData.locations[item].unit
      : '-',
    allData.locations[item] 
      ? allData.locations[item].value + allData.locations[item].currency
      : '-',
  ]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this doe not work when the array increase dynamically- more like hardcoded approach

Comment: @Mangrio you always can wrap conversion logic into separate method and call it when you need (on data changes commonly)